# How to prevent cursor jump to next line in fixed column textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a textarea with the following HTML...

```html
 <textarea id="inputFreeContentArea" cols="16" rows="6" maxlength="96" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```

When the user enters text, I want the cursor to stop moving when 16 characters are entered in a line, it should not automatically move to next line, only if the user hits the enter key. Furthermore, it should not be possible to exceed 6 rows.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not rather pile six `input type=text` elements to look like a textarea ..?

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant I think the cursor would not jump to the next input field when hitting the enter key. Furthermore I would prefer to not collect the input from 6 different fields.

Comment: Add an event listener which detects the ENTER, and focuses to the next input. The code for ENTER detection and input collecting would be significantly simpler than trying to change the native behavior of the textarea element.

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jt6sravx/) for you. I assume collecting the value to a hidden input is trivial.

Comment: Start the text area off at maxlength 16 and add 16 to it every time the user presses enter. Since a max of 16 chars per row and max of 6 rows is almost the same as saying that every row should be max 16 long. Then you can add a newline every 16 characters to keep the 'row' structure. But that's more code than teemu's solution, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: A textarea is a bit complex for the task, you'd need to filter this and that, ex. pasting a string containing a new-line causes harm. Input element filters some difficulties automatically.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant Thanks for the demo, it already comes close to what I wanted. For the user experience it would be great if using the arrow keys would change the line, but I'm sure this could also be done by event listeners. I thought there would be an easier solution with less code (e.g. simply a textarea attribute to set), but if there is none, your answer is already fine.

Comment: @Shilly But what if the user for example enters 5 chars in the first line and then hits enter to proceed in the next line? The maxlength would be 32, allowing to enter 27 chars in line 2.

Comment: @boketto, add 11 spaces to the text before adding the newline. Hence again, using a `<textarea>` for this is the wrong tech if you want to change alot of default behaviour, since you have to account for all these weird quirks the user can throw at you. So you kinda have to choose between concatting 6 different fields or writing a big formatter function for the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a simple way to achieve what you want, that would require a lot of code and input checking. Instead, you could use a wrapper and six `input` elements, style them a bit, and collect the values to a hidden input ex. realtime or in a form validator. Something like this:

```js
function createTxtarea(parent, cols) {
  // Set the cols of the "textarea"
  const inputs = parent.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach(input => input.setAttribute('maxlength', cols));
  // Add listener for Enter and ArrowUp/down keys
  const focusTo = {
    Enter: (e) => e.target.nextElementSibling,
    ArrowDown(e) {return this.Enter(e);},
    ArrowUp: (e) => e.target.previousElementSibling
  };
  parent.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const key = e.key;
    if (typeof focusTo[key] === 'function') {
      e.preventDefault();
      const prext = focusTo[key](e);
      if (prext) prext.focus();
    }
    // Collect the value here if needed
  });
}

createTxtarea(document.getElementById('area1'), 16);
```

```css
.txtarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.txtarea input {
  border: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="area1" class="txtarea">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
    <input type="text" name="area1[]">
  </div>
</form>
```

Suffixing the input names with `[]` makes them available as an array at the back-end, that way you can easily extract a single value from the inputs at the server too.

You can improve the basic code. It is easy to create multiple "txtareas", and the code can be converted to OOP if needed, and it's possible to create the inputs and even the parent element dynamically.

The code is ignored in phones, but filling the "txtarea" is still fluent. If you added the `maxlength` attributes to HTML, "txtarea" would work more fluently than a customized real textarea element, if JS is turned off.