# How do I make div or <li> accessible through Up/down arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

So I have a few `div`s one below the other. I want them to be "web accessible" via arrows keys, i.e, if I press the down key next `div` should be highlighted and if I press the up key, the previous one should be highlighted.

If I had a button I could have used the `tabIndex` property to achieve it.

The thing is `div`s are not actionable items. So it could be confusing for the users if I make them somehow accessible through tabs. Hence, I want it only through arrow keys of the keyboard.

I'm even willing to convert it into `<ul><li><li></ul>` if the desired behavior could be achieved.

```html
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
<div>Div 4</div>
```

This is what I tried with `<li>`s. But If I click on the first `li` I cant go and highlight the next one by pressing the down arrow.

```html
<ul role="menu" aria-label="menu">
            <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0">list 1</li>
            <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0">list 2</li>
            <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0">list 3</li>
            <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0">list 4</li>
            <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0">list 5</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please define "accessible div".

Comment: @Teemu Accessibility (web accessibility) as in accessible for the differently-abled users who rely on keyboard for navigation or to read the content of a page.

Comment: But what it means in practice? Do you want to highlight a div, or just scroll to it or something else?

Comment: Convert these to ul lis then

Comment: @Teemu yup highlighting is enough.

Comment: @Asutosh can you show a working example. I did try this in fact. But could get the `<li>`'s highlighted.

Comment: [Not a direct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630408/1169519), but maybe you get some ideas ... The question would be better, if you'd show what've you tried, so that we won't represent you some solutions you've already abandonded.

Comment: @Teemu sure. Just updated.

Comment: you can review the official guides here https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1. that provides live examples and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should use jquery for what you want. Your last source will be this:

```js
$(function(){
        document.onkeydown = function(e) {
            var selected = $('.mnu-item:focus').index();

            var next = selected + 1;
            var pre = selected - 1;

            if(pre < 0)
                pre = 0;
            if(next > $('.mnu-item').length)
                next = $('.mnu-item').length;

            if(e.which == 38) { // up
                $('.mnu-item').eq(pre).focus();
            }
            if(e.which == 40) { // down
                $('.mnu-item').eq(next).focus();
            }
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
        };
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul role="menu" aria-label="menu">
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" class="mnu-item">list 1</li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" class="mnu-item">list 2</li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" class="mnu-item">list 3</li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" class="mnu-item">list 4</li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" class="mnu-item">list 5</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Hmm I see that. I wanted to avoid jquery/javascript. But looks like that's the only way. Btw any idea how to do this with react-hooks?

Comment: You have another way and you can write a comment under your list and say use "Tab button to change the selected row". But I don't know react and I have no idea about that!

Comment: No worries. I’ll bind the events of keyup and key down in react to accomplish it. The point is we’ll have to intercept key press events to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ARIA widget that allows for keyboard navigation via arrow keys, with one tab stop instead of many: your list of similar `<div>`s can be formulated as a single-column [Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#grid).

Initially, the cell in the first row gets `tabindex="0"` and all others get `tabindex="-1"`.

Using JavaScript, arrowing down focuses the cell in the second row. It gets `tabindex="0"` while the cell in the first row gets `tabindex="-1"`, so that there is only ever one cell that is tabbable/focusable. The full keyboard handling is specified in the [examples/docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/grid/dataGrids.html).

In JavaScript, you will need to keep track of currently focused item.

Here's how I would set it up using React:

```
class MyGrid extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            focusedItemIndex: 0
        }

        this.cellRefs = []

        this.handleFocus = (index => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                focusedItemIndex: index
            }))
        }).bind(this)

        this.handleKeydown = ((index, {
            key
        }) => {
            switch (key) {
                case 'ArrowUp': {
                    this.setState(() => ({
                        focusedItemIndex: Math.max(0, index - 1)
                    }))
                }
                break
                case 'ArrowDown': {
                    this.setState(() => ({
                        focusedItemIndex: Math.min(index + 1, this.props.items.length - 1)
                    }))
                }
                break
                case 'Home': {
                    this.setState(() => ({
                        focusedItemIndex: 0
                    }))
                }
                break
                case 'End': {
                    this.setState(() => ({
                        focusedItemIndex: this.props.items.length - 1
                    }))
                }
                break
                default: {
                    return
                }
            }
        }).bind(this)
    }
    componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
        if (prevState.focusedItemIndex !== this.state.focusedItemIndex) {
            this.cellRefs[this.state.focusedItemIndex].focus()
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div
                role="grid"
                aria-label="This needs a label">
                <div role="row">
                    {this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div
                            role="cell"
                            key={item}
                            ref={el => this.cellRefs[index] = el}
                            tabIndex={this.state.focusedItemIndex === index ? '0' : '-1'}
                            onFocus={this.handleFocus.bind(this, index)}
                            onKeyDown={this.handleKeydown.bind(this, index)}>
                            {item}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyGrid items={['A', 'B', 'C']} />,
    document.querySelector('body')
)
```

Comment: Considering that the OP neither tagged nor mentioned React, exactly how appropriate do you imagine this response is?

Comment: @floodlitworld In a comment OP asks if the jQuery answer version is available in React, so I used React to get them close to something they could use. I don't think this deserved a downvote.