# Move cursor from one contenteditable to the next

Tags: javascript, html, cursor-position

I am currently trying to implement a simple text editor that uses one `<span>` for  every sentence. Every sentence can be edited. I am trying to implement that you can move the cursor to the next span when you reached the end of the the previous element.

Given the following code:

```
<span contenteditable style="background: red; color: white">This is the first element.</span>
<span contenteditable style="background: green; color: white">This is the second element.</span>
```

and the cursor placed at the `.` of `This is the first element.`, when now pressing the `RIGHT-ARROW`-Key I would like to move the cursor to the beginning of the next sentence.

I have no idea where to start. Does somebody has an idea how this could be possible?

https://jsfiddle.net/ (the only way to switch from the first to the second sentence is by using the TAB key)

Comment: Perhaps you can get some ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630408/1169519) ..?