# Styling a text input as a date input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a text input that looks like a date input (check the code snippet). I want it to be seamless because how I have it setup now I can't press backspace to delete the value of the field before it. Is it possible to do it with one textfield? And if not how would I do it with javascript. (I did not include the javascript I already wrote)

Please ask me if I need to clarify anything.

```css
#birthday{
    font-size:13px;
    padding: 5px;
    width:120px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    #birthday-span{
        margin-left: -133px;
        color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.4);
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        
    }
    .input-birthday{
        font-size: 13px;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        margin: 3px;
        color: black;
    }
    #month,#day{
        width: 25px;
    }
    #year{
        width: 35px;
    }
```

```html
<input type='text' id='birthday' disabled>
                    <span id='birthday-span'>
                        <input type='text' name='month' id='month' placeholder="MM" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
                        <input type='text' name='day' id='day' placeholder="DD" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
                        <input type='text' name='year' id='year' placeholder="YYYY" class='input-birthday' maxlength="4">
                    </span>
```

Comment: [Here's a code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630408/1169519) doing something similar you need row-wise, it should be easy to change that snippet to work column-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the an answer for your comment
it includes shifting to next input the max length has reached and also switching to the previous one on backspace

```js
document.getElementById("day").onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleChange("day", e)
}
document.getElementById("year").onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleChange("year", e)
}
document.getElementById("month").onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleChange("month", e)
}

function handleChange(id, e) {
  document.getElementById(id).value.length === 0 && e.key === "Backspace" && document.getElementById(id === "day" ? "month" : id === "year" && "day") && document.getElementById(id === "day" ? "month" : id === "year" ? "day" : "").focus()

  document.getElementById(id).value.length === document.getElementById(id).maxLength && e.key !== "Backspace" && document.getElementById(id === "month" ? "day" : id === "day" && "year") && document.getElementById(id === "month" ? "day" : id === "day" ? "year" : "").focus()

}
```

```css
#birthday {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.input-birthday {
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  color: black;
}

#month,
#day {
  width: 25px;
}

#year {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<span id='birthday'>
    <input type='text' name='month' id='month' placeholder="MM" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
    <input type='text' name='day' id='day' placeholder="DD" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
    <input type='text' name='year' id='year' placeholder="YYYY" class='input-birthday' maxlength="4" >
</span>
```

Comment: How about a case OP needs two or more similar date elements on the same page? This won't be an ideal solution.

Comment: @Teemu you're right .i added another post which i think would be the final post on this subject and wrote a dynamic code for it.

Comment: You should probably delete this answer (for future reference, it's also okay to edit a post instead of posting a new answer)

Answer (score 1):

i hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
document.getElementById("day").onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleChange("day", e)
}
document.getElementById("year").onkeydown = function(e) {
  handleChange("year",e)
}

function handleChange(id, e) {
  document.getElementById(id).value.length === 0 && e.key === "Backspace" && document.getElementById(id === "day" ? "month" : id === "year" ? "day" : "").focus()
}
```

```css
#birthday {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.input-birthday {
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  color: black;
}

#month,
#day {
  width: 25px;
}

#year {
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<span id='birthday'>
    <input type='text' name='month' id='month' placeholder="MM" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
    <input type='text' name='day' id='day' placeholder="DD" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
    <input type='text' name='year' id='year' placeholder="YYYY" class='input-birthday' maxlength="4" >
</span>
```

Comment: How would I make it so that it switches to the next field when it has reached its max length?

Comment: @bdb8 i editted my post according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements with `document.createElement("elementTagName"). ie:

if i can write below for creating a div element :

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
```

Also you can add any element you want a child element with `appenChild()` methods, shown below:

```
let a = document.createElement("a");
div.appendChild(a);
```

The codes above is equal below :

```
<div> 
    <a></<a>
</div>
```

You can search that is Javascript DOM(document object manupulation) methods. I hope this would be helpfull for your question.

Answer (score 0):

a more dynamic version of my post from earlier
@Teemu

```js
Object.values(document.getElementById("birthday").children).map(el => {
  el.onkeydown = function(e) {
    handleChange(el.name, el, e)
  }
})

function handleChange(id, element, e) {
  element.value.length === 0 && e.key === "Backspace" &&
    element.previousElementSibling && element.previousElementSibling.focus()

  element.value.length === element.maxLength && e.key !== "Backspace" && element.nextElementSibling && element.nextElementSibling.focus()

}
```

```css
#birthday {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.input-birthday {
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  color: black;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<span id='birthday'>
    <input type='text' name='month' placeholder="MM" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
    <input type='text' name='day' placeholder="DD" maxlength='2' class='input-birthday'>/
    <input type='text' name='year' placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4"  class='input-birthday' >
</span>
```

Comment: This is technically invalid because you are not allowed to have multiple elements with the same ID on a page.

Comment: @ZachSaucier you're right about the fact that we should not have multiple elements with the same ID on a page, but this is not the case. there is only one id of "birthday".

Comment: Right, but anytime you need to have multiple of these elements, it immediately becomes invalid. It makes much more sense not to use IDs here