# HTML Textarea partially editable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

I want a `textarea` to be partially editable. The first column should be not editable and the second should be the place where the user will input this "answer".

The first column is people early, late and night and everything after that the user should be able to insert and everything before should readonly.

The script is only working for inline text but my text should be row1, row2 and row3 and I do not know how do it.

```js
$('#people').keydown(function() {
  if ($(this).val().indexOf('people early: 
      people late:
      people night: ') !== 0) {
    var length = "This is constant.  ".length;
    var current = $(this).val();
    var after = current.slice(length);

    $(this).val("This is constant.  " + after);
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="people">
     people early: 
     people late:
     people night:
    </textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use a grid and input elements instead, that would be a lot simpler.

Comment: @Teemu how can i do that? can you show an example please?

Comment: Don't use a single textarea for this. It may be possible to hack some JS together to do it, it would be incredibly brittle, ridiculously easy to work around and the data it generates would not be granular should need to extend the functionality of this logic in the future. Use multiple fields for each row & column, dynamically appending new rows if necessary.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630408/1169519). It doesn't use a grid, but it's easy to add (something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yfzr5Lv4/)).

Answer (score -1):

I assume you should use 3 different inputs to get the 3 information you want then format a string to makes it look how you want it to be.

Comment: this would add a complexity unnecessary to a form, it should deserialize and serialize again. Well of course this would be a solution for short term :(